# How to upload multipe files in angular and laravel with html table?

Tags: php, laravel, angular7, multiple-file-upload

> I am having one html dynamic form one dropdown list of companies. If
>   user will select any of the company from dropdown it will show
>   respective employees of particular company in table.With each row of i
>   am attaching input[file]. Now user will upload payslip of each
>   employee and save data. my concern is to upload each rows files into
>   database into different row.

component.html :

```
<table *ngIf="allemp">
  <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name of Employee</th>
      <th>Attached Payslip</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data1 of allemp">
      <td>{{data1.id}}</td>
      <td>{{data1.emp_name}}</td>
        <input formArrayName='payslip' type="file" (change)="onFileChangeInfo($event,i)" multiple></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

function for multiple uplaods in ts file:

```
  onFileChangeInfo(event,index) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      var filesAmount = event.target.files.length;
      this.items= this.myForm1.controls['payslip'] as FormArray;
      console.log(this.items);
        if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
          const [files] = event.target.files;
          this.regInfoName=event.target.files[0].name;
          this.urlInfoUploadd= event.target.result;

          for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
          reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
          reader.onload = () => {
            this.urlInfoUpload = this.urlInfoUploadd;
            this.regInfoNameHtml=this.regInfoName;
            this.items.controls[index].patchValue({
              'data_blob': reader.result,
              'data_file':files.name,

          });
            console.log(files.name);
            this.cd.markForCheck();
          };
        }

      }
  }
```

on console.log(filesAmount) it shows me all selected files. But in database goes only last file.

i dont understand what's wrong in my code. please help me with the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar experience like this in ReactJS before. Hence, i will try my best to re-write the code I used for you.

You can use Promise.all() to load an array of files asynchronously:

```
onFileChangeInfo(event) {
   const files = Array.from(event.target.files); // Get files in array form

   // Map each file to a promise that resolves an array of files
   const promises = files.map(file => {
      return (new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
         const reader = new FileReader();
         reader.addEventListener('load', (ev) => {
            resolve(ev.target.result);
         }
         reader.addEventListener('error', reject);
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
   });

   // Once all promises are resolved, store the file blob in your variable
   Promise.all(promises).then(files => {
      this.items.controls.patchValue({ 
         'data_blob': files 
      }, 
   }, error => { console.error(error); });
}
```

I don't know how your code looks like so i don't know what you're using the "index" parameter for. But if `this.items.controls` is an array where you want to store each file blob, then you don't need the "index".